# NumberFormatException - how to fix it?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, numberformatexception

When I enter `jTextField2` before I enter `jTextField1` I get this error stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at suvatcalc.CalculatorFrame.jTextField2KeyReleased(CalculatorFrame.java:263)
at suvatcalc.CalculatorFrame.access$200(CalculatorFrame.java:14)
at suvatcalc.CalculatorFrame$3.keyReleased(CalculatorFrame.java:78)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6500)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is the code:

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        String displacementString = jTextField1.getText();
        displacement = Double.parseDouble(displacementString);
        System.out.println(displacement);
    }
}                                       

private void jTextField2KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        String initialVelocityString = jTextField1.getText();
        initialVelocity = Double.parseDouble(initialVelocityString);
        System.out.println(initialVelocity);
    }

}
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. The program requires me to enter the text boxes only in order which I assume is a result of the way I wrote the program.

Comment: NumberFormatException - You are passing a nonnumeric value to Double.parseDouble method

Comment: Use proper validatation for input field

Comment: Did you try to understand what the Exception is telling you?

Comment: A better approach altogether: `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(..));`

Answer (score 0):

In your method `jTextField2KeyReleased()` you are trying to parse a non numeric value into `Double` object -> `initialVelocity = Double.parseDouble(initialVelocityString);`

You can use a proper validation by using regex, or to catch the `NumberFormatException` and ask the user for a proper input.